# How Do I Disable "missing java doc" warning in netbeans code inspection?

Tags: java, netbeans-7, findbugs, netbeans-plugins

I'm using netbeans 7.3 ide on ubuntu. I've installed the findBugz plugin and when running source->inspect I get a lot of suggestions/errors. One that I would like to ignore in this time is "Missing javadoc" (when I run "all analyzers"). How can I do that? I found that I can configure other errors (to be ignored in a specific line or all together) if it relates to a java hint (then I can press the small black arrow and configure it the  way I want). But with this error - there's no little black error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one way I know how.  After clicking Inspect from the Source menu, create a new Custom configuration by clicking Manage button next to the Configuration drop down after you've chosen a custom configuration.  Then you have to manually check all of the boxes for both FindBugs and NetBeans Java Hints **EXCEPT JavaDoc->Create Javadoc**  This runs all analyzers  except the one that displays "Missing javadoc."  Not ideal, but I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm. edited my default and now I'm java doc error free

Answer (score 1):

Disable "Error in Javadoc" option, on Hints tab:

[image: disable "Error in Javadoc" option, on Hints tab]

Comment: thanks for replying but using your mrthod isn't permanent. Once I rerun "inspect" on the source the error/hint reappers...

Comment: I did this because the previous answer wasn't working for me. I am using Netbeans 8